# Page Loaded Event not firing WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, event-handling

I have a simple page in WPF. The MainPage() constructor runs fine which I can see using breakpoints. I have a breakpoint on the first line in the MainPage_Loaded() function and it never gets executed and the page doesn't load.

I have the following code. It was running fine up until I turned off my computer and went back to try and use it again. I have enabled all Exceptions in Visual Studio but nothing gets thrown. Any ideas would be appreciated.

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainPage_Loaded);
}

void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     //Code.....
}
```

Comment: Try adding Loaded="MainPage_Loaded" in the window tag in the xaml and ditch the Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainPage_Loaded); in the code.

Or change the code to this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainPage_Loaded);

Answer (score 0):

So I went to **Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General** and then unticked **Enable Just My Code (Managed only)**.

When I did this an Exception was thrown and this lead me to the problem. I had referenced a non-existent element in my XAML but the exception wasn't been thrown in my code so it wasn't been shown.